# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket, I'm not the server admin (using hosting plan)

Tags: php, mysql, sockets

I'm trying to connect to my SQL database and I'm getting the error mentioned above.

**This is the PHP code**

```
// This file has database info variables (password etc.)
include "db_config.php";

class DB_CONNECT
{
function __construct()
{
    $this->connect();
}

function __destruct(){}

function connect()
{
    $connect = mysql_connect($db_server, $db_user, $db_password) or die();
    $db = mysql_select_db($db_name) or die();
    echo "Connection successful!";
    return $connect;
}
}

// Just to try out if the connection is successful
new DB_CONNECT();
```

**This is the error**

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in /hermes/bosnaweb05a/b1/ipg.matejhacincom1/dbtest/db_connect.php on line 16

**The funny thing is that I can connect to the database easily with this code which is generated for db testing by my hosting provider:**

```
$link = mysql_connect('my db server', 'db user', 'db pass'); 
if (!$link) { 
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
echo 'Connected successfully'; 
mysql_select_db(my db table);
```

Could someone let me know what I'm doing wrong? I have no idea anymore.

*The reason I mentioned that I'm not the server adming is because I saw a lot of questions like this here, but all of them have instructions how to solve it by using some server commands etc.*

Comment: **Warning**:  You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: Thank you very much! I was not aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

Either:

- There isn't a MySQL server running on the same machine as the webserver *or*
- The MySQL server is configured to place its socket file somewhere other than `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` (in which case you need to [specify where it is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6152178/19068) *or*
- The MySQL server is configured to listen only on TCP/IP (which is inefficient but it can be accessed by using the `127.0.0.1` IP address instead of `localhost`).

Answer (score 0):

Probably in variables `$db_server, $db_user, $db_password` you have wrong data. You must pass to object data from `db_config.php` file. For example through constructor.

Comment: There is no way that supplying the wrong username or password could produce that error.

Comment: Of course it can produce error, because when Whiz connect outside of the method class it's working.

Comment: No, it has to be a problem with the connection string because the error message says that the connection failed, not that the login was rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem on an customer server, last week, then :

- Be sure your `$db_server` is according your hosting ; not a remote server.
- Then use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`

*In my case, the MySQL server was different the PHP.*

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for all of your answers but what solved my problem was nothing that was in any of your answers.

All I did was used PDO instead of deprecated mysql and it worked. I also for some reason needed to move inclulde "db_config.php" in to the class because variables didn't work otherwise.

Anyway, here's the code that now works:

```
class DB_CONNECT
{
function __construct()
{
    $this->connect();
}

function __destruct(){}

function connect()
{
    include "db_config.php";
    $connect = new PDO($db_server, $db_user, $db_password) or die();
    echo "Connection successful!";
    return $connect;
}
}

// Just to try out if the connection is successful
new DB_CONNECT();
```