# PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: php, mamp

I have put PushChatServer dir in htdocs folder and create database puschat try to run @"http://localhost/PushChatServer/api/test/database.php"

Then I got following exception.

I want do same thing to explain this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/32963/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-2

I have done all that but I got this exception

> Could not connect to the database. Reason: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PushChatServer/api/test/database.php:17 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PushChatServer/api/test/database.php(17): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', 'root', Array) #1 {main}

Comment: Hope someone can answer it, because from my point of view the problem should be better described...

Comment: I guess you have wrong credential for your mysql defined (mysql hostname, user, password)

Comment: where can I check mysql credential? @Marki555

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error on creating connection to PDO in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435445/error-on-creating-connection-to-pdo-in-php)

Comment: Look at documentation of that "PushChatServer". Usually there is some file like `config.php`. Right now it is using default values (localhost and empty user and password), that's why it is not working for you

Comment: @Marki555 actually I have done same thing as per this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/32963/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-2

Comment: So you have MySQL running on your host as per the tutorial, you have set the pushchat database and database user via phpmyadmin and it still doesn't work?

Comment: yes MySql running. all things work expected. except database connection   @Marki555

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - MySQL connection not working: 2002 No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676688/php-mysql-connection-not-working-2002-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 55):

**You need to change host from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`**

Laravel 4: In your `app/config/database.php` try changing host from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`

Laravel 5: In the `.env` file, change `DB_HOST` from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`

Source: [PDOException SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723803/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: For whatever weird reason this worked for me - nextcloud on MySQL.

Answer (score 27):

Quick test (run in shell):

```
php -r "new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'username', 'password');"
```

**SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory** means php cannot find the mysql.default_socket file. Fix it by modifying php.ini file. On Mac it is *mysql.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock* (See [MySQL connection not working: 2002 No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676688/php-mysql-connection-not-working-2002-no-such-file-or-directory))

**SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost'** CONGRATULATION! You have the correct mysql.default_socket setting now. Fix your dbname/username/password.

Also see [Error on creating connection to PDO in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435445/error-on-creating-connection-to-pdo-in-php)

Comment: Thank you!  This worked for me.  I'm using PHP 7.1.9 on Mac OS X 10.10 running mysql 5.7 server from macport.  For macport's mysql, mysql.sock lives at /opt/local/var/run/mysql57/mysqld.sock.  I encountered this error trying to run 'php artisan migrate:install' using laravel 5.5.

Comment: hello community , i am getting similar error even though i am not using laravel can you look at the problem here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60796332/this-php-code-works-in-localhost-but-not-on-server

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error using PHP 5.6.30 (macOS Sierra) with the simple PDO code like:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_php', 'root', '');
```

And I received the same error message. To fix, I changed "localhost" for IP (loopback) "127.0.0.1" in my code:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=db_php', 'root', '');
```

To test the connection:

```
$ php -r "new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=db_php', 'root', '');"
```

This work's for me!

Answer (score 4):

Restart your database and local web server:

```
sudo service mysqld restart
```

It should work!

Comment: This has been down-voted presumably because it's not a very 'technical' answer, but it worked for me, so an up-vote seems only fair.

Answer (score 4):

PDO treats localhost very particularly:

From http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php:

> Note: Unix only: When the host name is set to "localhost", then the
>   connection to the server is made thru a domain socket. If PDO_MYSQL is
>   compiled against libmysqlclient then the location of the socket file
>   is at libmysqlclient's compiled in location. If PDO_MYSQL is compiled
>   against mysqlnd a default socket can be set thru the
>   pdo_mysql.default_socket setting.

That why PDO and mysql_connect will give different behavior for localhost.

**So, if you want to use a TCP connection with PDO, never use localhost but 127.0.0.1.**

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this will work for you; but I use CakePHP, and I get this error whenever I forget to put the port number at the end of the 'host'.

Hope this helps!

**Before**

```
'test' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'root',
        'database' => 'mylogin',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
        'log' => false,
        //'init' => ['SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0'],
        'url' => env('DATABASE_TEST_URL', null),
    ]
```

**After**

```
'test' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost:8080',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'root',
        'database' => 'mylogin',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
        'log' => false,
        //'init' => ['SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0'],
        'url' => env('DATABASE_TEST_URL', null),
    ]
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error for Mysql PDO, this code works for me!

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=testdb';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$options = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
); 

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
?>
```

got this code from : http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php

Answer (score 3):

Run the following command in shell, I think it will help.

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear 
php artisan view:clear
```

Comment: I really didn't expect to solution to be that easy, but sir this three lines solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OSX/MAMP you may find a mysql.sock.lock file in your /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql folder.

You can safely remove the file mysql.sock.lock and you should be in good shape.

Answer (score 0):

Happy to report PDO socket can now be adjusted directly in /etc/php.ini, even though older sources indicate it can be specified only when compiling php/pdo:

```
[Pdo_mysql]
pdo_mysql.default_socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[MySQLi]
mysqli.default_socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[MySQL]
mysql.default_socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Source [PHP set MySQL socket location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151995/php-set-mysql-socket-location)

Answer (score -1):

Just ran into this same issue and the problem is the password. In the tutorial the author lists the password as:

```
"d]682\#%yl1nb3"
```

So as per the suggestion given by @Marki555, I looked in the config file - api_config.php. and the password listed there is:

```
"d]682\#%yI1nb3"
```

The upper case 'I' is what caused the issue because the password you set for user on the db has the password with the lowercase l but it really is looking for the uppercase I. After I changed the pushchat user's password to have an uppercase i, it worked!