# SQLState[HY000] Connection refused Laravel with docker

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker

I'm setting up an existing Laravel project on my local machine using Docker. I realize similar questions have been asked many different times and the common refrain is "change `DB_HOST` to `127.0.0.1`, however, my project already has that set.

Whenever I try to run: `docker-compose exec app php artisan migrate:install` to set the DB up I get this error:

```
In Connection.php line 664:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: create table `migrations` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment prima
  ry key, `migration` varchar(255) not null, `batch` int not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)


In Connector.php line 67:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

.env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3385*
DB_DATABASE=project
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
services: 
...
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.5
    ports:
      - 3385:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=project
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/mysql
```

Using the above credentials I am able to successfully connect to the database through a tool like SQLPro or `docker-compose exec mysql bash`.  I know this is likely a configuration issue but I'm not sure what the problem is, Laravel, and really the PHP world, are not my forte.

*This is not the default port, the default port dosen't work either, I changed the port number so it wouldn't conflict with an instance of MySQL I have running locally.

Comment: Did you try `DB_HOST=mysql`? Otherwise, you are making the php contianer connect to itself, not your actual database server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `app` container service would need to connect to `mysql:3306`, so

```
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
```

If you don't need to connect to MySQL from the host, then you don't need the `ports` section at all.

Comment: Thanks! So in `docker-compose.yml` what is the order of ports.  Since I have `3385:3306` is `3385` the Docker port and 3306 is the MySQL port? Or am I off base there?

Comment: It's a port forward from the Docker network onto your host network interface - format of  `host:container`