# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, connection-refused

Using Laravel 8

Ubuntu 20.04 with Docker

Connect to Database over clients worked perfect. Docker-Container worked.

If I dont start it with `php artisan serve` it refused the connection to mysql.

With `php artisan serve` it connects to mysql-docker-container.

I want deploy it. But if I make it like this doc: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/deployment
it worked fine, but only DB-connection crashes.

I tried: [SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused within Laravel homestead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35394230/sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-refused-within-laravel-homestead)

But if I change the Host it answer with this mistake: [PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29695450/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory)

need help.

Comment: So `php artisan serve` connects to the database when you run it in the docker container?

Comment: in docker-container it would start too. I tested it know.
But I dont start ```php artisan serve``` in docker. 
For what I need docker if I start it into docker ? I use it with docker to test deploying

Comment: So in general you can't connect to the database from within the docker container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont forget... WSL :)

use `mysql` not localhost.